# Creando una clase vistaMensaje, ¿Como puedo crear los mensajes personaliazdos y con estilo a partir de esa clase? PHP

Tags: php

¿Como se le prodria dar un nuevo comportamiento a modo de mensaje de error o aviso añadiendole estilos a la siguiente clase?

```
<?php

class VistaMensaje{

// Atributos
private $_mensaje;

// Getters y Setters

/// Construccion
public function __construct(string $pMensaje){
    $this->_mensaje = $pMensaje;
}

// Métodos de interface
public function imprimir(){ 
    echo($this->_mensaje);
}

}
```

la parte en la que quiero mostrar el mensaje personalizado seria en esta:

```
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__ ."/../view/VistaMenuSecretario.php");
require_once(__DIR__ ."/../view/VistaMensaje.php");
require_once(__DIR__ ."/../view/VistaMatricularAlumno.php");

class MenuSecretario {

// Atributos
private $_secretario;

// Getters y Setters


// Construccion
public function __construct(Secretario $pSecretario){
    $this->_secretario = $pSecretario;
}

// Métodos de interface
public function procesaAccion(array $request){
    $accion = !isset($request["accion"]) ? 0 : $request["accion"];
    if($accion == 0){
        return [$this->getMenu(), new VistaMensaje("Selecciona una opción")];
    }
    else if($this->esAccionValida($accion)){
        switch($accion){
            case 1:
                $alumno = $this->_secretario->getAlumnoFromDni($request["dni"]);
                return [new VistaMatricularAlumno($alumno, $this->_secretario)];
            case 2:
                $alumno = $this->_secretario->getAlumnoFromDni($request["dni"]);
                foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
                    $materia = $this->_secretario->getMateriaPorCodigo($key);
                    if($materia != null){
                        $alumno->matricularEnMateria($materia);
                    }
                }
                return [$this->getMenu(), new VistaMensaje("Alumno Matriculado correctamente")];
            case 3:
                //TODO
                break;
            case 4:
                //TODO:
                break;
            case 5:
                session_destroy();
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383371/refresh-a-page-using-php
                header("Location: login.php");
                die;
            default: 
                //TODO:
        }
    }
    else{
        //echo("Acción inválida");
        //TODO:
    }
}

public function getMenu(){
    return new VistaMenuSecretario();
}

// Métodos privados
private function esAccionValida($pAccion){
    $params = array(
        'options' => array(
            'default' => false, // valor a retornar si el filtro falla
            'min_range' => 1,
            'max_range' => 5)
        );

    //http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php
    return filter_var($pAccion, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $params);
}
}
```

Comment: No se entiende bien tu pregunta. ¿Qué tipo de error quieres manejar por ejemplo (el mensaje es nulo, el mensaje es demasiado corto, el mensaje no contiene las palabras XYZ, el mensaje ...)?. Convendría que pongas un ejemplo y que nos digas lo que has investigado / intentado.

Comment: estoy validadndo las opciones de un menu, y para cuando no indicas una opcion válida tengo que mostrar un mensaje personalizado en rojo a partir de esa clase, y no se muy bien como sacarlo @A.Cedano

Comment: Independientemente de la lógica que estás siguiendo, la cual aparte de no entenderla del todo la veo un poco enrevesada en algunos puntos... Dado que tienes una vista, podrías dotarla de un método que formatee los mensajes de error, aplicando allí estilos. Así, cuando sea un error, pasas el contenido del texto por ese método el cual aplica algo así como una clase CSS al texto devolviendo algo como esto: `<p class="error">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>`, luego por CSS en la clase `error` das el formato propio a los textos de error. Tan simple como eso, no le veo más misterio al tema.

Comment: creo que lo entiendo, gracias, voy a tratar de hace lo que me dices a ver si doy sacado algo

Comment: Por decir algo, al constructor de `VistaMensaje` le puedes agregar un segundo parámetro opcional, que puede ser un código para identificar si es un mensaje del tipo `error`, o del tipo `info`, o del tipo `advertencia`, etc. Para facilitar puedes usar números o una letra y crear tu propia convención. Por ejemplo: `new VistaMensaje("Esto es un error",0);` o `new VistaMensaje("Esto es un error","e");` luego la clase lee ese segundo parámetro y aplicar al texto la clase que corresponda. Puedes definit constantes también, así queda elegante y profesional:  `new VistaMensaje("Esto es un error",E);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mandale un Html con el estilo que quieras para cada tipo de evento a tu método;

*public function imprimir(){ 
    echo($this->_mensaje);
}*

Y luego lo imprimes, retornas o empaquetas en un JSON para pasárselo a tu interfaz de usuario.

Incluso puedes crear un nuevo método como genHtmlError(). Deberías ir mirando el principio MVC para tener codigo más ordenado y flexibilidad para esas cosas.